# R passing data frame to another program using system()

Tags: r, input, stdin

I have a data frame that I pass to another program using `system()`.  In the current setup, I first write the contents of the dataframe to a text file, then have the `system()` command look for the created text file.

```
df1 <- runif(20)
write(df1, file="file1.txt")
system("myprogram file1.txt")
```

I have 2 questions:

1) Is there a way to pass a dataframe directly without writing the text file?

2) If not, is there are way to pass the data in memory as a text formatted entity without writing the file to disk?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: How long is a typical data frame? One option would be to pass the data as parameters to the command, but I think what you've already done is probably cleaner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write to anything R calls connections, and that includes network sockets.

So process A can write to the network, and process B can read it without any file-on-disk involved, see `help(connections)` which even has a working example in the "Examples" section.

Your general topic here is serialization, and R does that for you.  You can also pass data that way to other programs using tools that encode metadata about your data structure -- as for example Google's Protocol Buffers (supported in R by the [RProtoBuf](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RProtoBuf) package).

Answer (score 0):

I spent quite a while and couldn't understand the accepted answer. But I figured out a workaround.

```
df1 <- runif(20)
system("myprogram /dev/stdin", input = write.table(df1))
```

However, according to documentation, the `input` argument will actually be redirected to a temp file, which I suppose will involve some i/o.